# Un-flatten list of data efficiently

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have have joined a few tables together which produces a dataset that looks like this:

```
GroupName: "Products and Services";
GroupSortOrder: 0
TopicName: "Money Transfer"
TopicOrder: 11
Question: "Money Transfer question 1"
Answer: "Money Transfer answer 1"
ItemOrder: 0
```

*[ repeated in a list for however many items ]*

My intention is to end up with a JSON result which looks like this:

```
var jsonResult = [{ 
   title: 'Products and Services', 
   order: 0, 
   items: [{
       text: 'Money Transfer',
       order: 11,
       questionsAndAnswers: [{
           question: 'Money transfer question 1',
           answer: 'Money transfer answer 1',
           order: 0
        }]
   }]
}];
```

I have tried a bunch of things including LINQ's GroupBy, which unfortunately places the grouped value in the key, and also cannot move the related values (order, items) along with the "group name".

Below is my closest attempt, which ends up with the correct groups and "group level data", however each group contains all of the topics and each topic has all of the questions, not just the ones which are related to that group and topic "category".

**UPDATED, CLOSER TO SOLUTION**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// First organizes all FAQ items by topic property, removes topic data by from item level and groups results by topic desc
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem">2d collection of all faq items to be restructured.</param>
        /// <param name="outErrors">Errors out.</param>
        /// <returns>JSON string containing questionAnswer data inside of related topic objects</returns>
        public string SortAndRestructureFaqItemsData(List<FAQQuestionAnswer> allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem, out string outErrors)
        {
            string jsonResult = string.Empty;
            string errors = string.Empty;

            // Final result, collection of unique groups
            List<FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers> groupsCollection = new List<FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers>();

            // Collection for FAQQuestionAnswerOnly.
            List<FAQQuestionAnswerOnly> faqItemsForTopic = new List<FAQQuestionAnswerOnly>();

            foreach (var faq in allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem)
            {   
                // Get topic name from faq data.
                string topicName = faq.TopicName;

                // Get group name from faq data.
                string groupName = faq.GroupName;

                // New temp topic.
                FAQTopicsWithItemsResult newTopic = new FAQTopicsWithItemsResult(topicName, faq.TopicOrder, faqItemsForTopic);

                // Check if this group exists.
                if (groupsCollection.Any(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == faq.GroupName))
                {
                    // Check if the topic exists inside of this group
                    if (groupsCollection.Any(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupTopics.Any(faqTopic => faqTopic.Title == topicName)))
                    {
                        // Since the and group exists, add the newTopic to it which also contains the first item.
                        groupsCollection.Find(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == groupName).GroupTopics.Find(faqTopic => faqTopic.Title == topicName).Items.Add(new FAQQuestionAnswerOnly(faq.Question, faq.Answer, faq.ItemOrder));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Since the group exists but not the topic, add the new topic containing the new item to the matching group.
                        groupsCollection.Find(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == groupName).GroupTopics.Add(newTopic);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Since this is a new group, add it along with the new topic, and faqItem
                    groupsCollection.Add(new FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers(groupName, faq.GroupSortOrder, new List<FAQTopicsWithItemsResult> { newTopic }));
                }
            }   

            try
            {
                jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupsCollection);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                errors = error.Message;
            }

            outErrors = errors;

            return jsonResult;
        }
```

I would post the result, but its too big. Here is an abbreviated version:

```
var jsonResult = [{ 
   title: 'Products and Services', 
   order: 0, 
   items: [{
       text: 'Money Transfer',
       order: 11,
       questionsAndAnswers: [{
           question: 'Money transfer question 1',
           answer: 'Money transfer answer 1',
           order: 0
        },
         { ... plus all items in all topics instead of just the ones in the 'Money Transfer' topic. }
      ]
   },
         { ... plus all topics in all groups, instead of just the ones in the 'Products and services' topic. }]
}];
```

Thanks in advance for any help that anyone can provide. I am open for an easier solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this on my own, which is exactly what I needed :)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// First organizes all FAQ items by topic property, removes topic data by from item level and groups results by topic desc
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem">2d collection of all faq items to be restructured.</param>
    /// <param name="outErrors">Errors out.</param>
    /// <returns>JSON string containing questionAnswer data inside of related topic objects</returns>
    public string SortAndRestructureFaqItemsData(List<FAQQuestionAnswer> allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem, out string outErrors)
    {
        string jsonResult = string.Empty;
        string errors = string.Empty;

        // Final result, collection of unique groups
        List<FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers> groupsCollection = new List<FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers>();

        foreach (var faq in allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem)
        {   
            // Get topic name from faq data.
            string topicName = faq.TopicName;

            // Get group name from faq data.
            string groupName = faq.GroupName;

            // Is this a new group or existing?
            bool groupExists = groupsCollection.Any(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == faq.GroupName);

            // Is this topic new or existing?
            bool topicExists = groupsCollection.Any(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupTopics.Any(faqTopic => faqTopic.Title == topicName));

            // New temp topic.
            FAQTopicsWithItemsResult newTopic = new FAQTopicsWithItemsResult(topicName, faq.TopicOrder, new List<FAQQuestionAnswerOnly>());

            // Check if this group exists.
            if (groupExists)
            {
                // Check if the topic exists inside of this group
                if (topicExists)
                {
                    // Since the and group exists, add the newTopic to it which also contains the first item.
                    groupsCollection.Find(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == groupName).GroupTopics.Find(faqTopic => faqTopic.Title == topicName).Items.Add(new FAQQuestionAnswerOnly(faq.Question, faq.Answer, faq.ItemOrder));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Since the group exists but not the topic, add the new topic containing the new item to the matching group.
                    groupsCollection.Find(faqGroup => faqGroup.GroupName == groupName).GroupTopics.Add(newTopic);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Since this is a new group, add it along with the new topic, and new faqItem
                groupsCollection.Add(new FAQGroupedTopicsItemsQuestionsAnswers(groupName, faq.GroupSortOrder, new List<FAQTopicsWithItemsResult> { newTopic }));
            }
        }   

        try
        {
            jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupsCollection);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            errors = error.Message;
        }

        outErrors = errors;

        return jsonResult;
    }
```